# Why does std::count_if return signed value instead of unsigned?

Tags: c++, stl, standard-library, stl-algorithm

Just realized that `std::count_if` [returns a signed value](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count_if/).

Why is it designed this way? It makes no sense (the result can only be a natural number, i. e. non-negative integer) in my opinion, as it doesn't allow doing something as simple as comparing this result to the container's `size()` without either getting a warning or using explicit type conversion.

I really think the return type should have `size_type`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It makes some sense to return the `difference_type` of the iterator for `count`, since it is pretty much just the difference of the arguments, it makes sense to keep that interface for `count_if`, and it equally makes some sense for the `difference_type` to be signed for bidirectional iterators.

Comment: Similarly why cannot one split two `std::list`s in a constant time?

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg: Simple, you need to count the elements. The list once created has O(1) `.size()` which implies it's cached,

Comment: @MSalters But you could store the position in the iterator that could be used for splitting list, hance it could be amortized...

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg: How would you keep that position current? Remember that you can call `push_front` on a list without invalidating existing iterators, and obviously that does change the position of all existing iterators by one.

Comment: @MSalters: yes I see your point here... Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

I think the return type aims to be compatible to `std::count` which takes two iterators (think of pointers) and return the values in between (which you can think of as a difference of two pointers). A pointer difference (as used in `ptrdiff_t`) has to be a signed value.

Thanks to the compatibility to `std::count` you can easily compare the results of these two functions.

Edit: There is no range related drawback using a signed value here, since the value will at least be in the range `[0, std::count]` which itself will be in the range `[0, end_ptr - start_ptr]`. Because `end_ptr - start_ptr` is typed as `ptrdiff_t` or similar, it's signed.

Comment: Nonsense. The `std::count` description clearly says: "Returns the **number of elements** in the range [first,last) that compare equal to val." Number of elements can't be negative. The type of `count` arguments (iterators) is entirely unrelated.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: Yes. Number of elements can't be negative. But the signatures of `count` and `count_if` both contain iterators. I didn't say it makes much sense to define a number of elements signed...